# cloud firestore - Consulta com campos do tipo Data

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, firebase, mobile, firebase-database

No aplicativo android que estou tentando montar, possuo uma tela de filtro por data de cadastro e preciso realizar a consulta no cloud firestore utilizando esse campo, no banco de dados ele é do tipo **Timestamp**.
Atualmente estou tentando realizar a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
    db.collection("Presenca")
                .whereGreaterThan("datacadastro", datacadastro)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                                alunosList.add(
                                        new Presenca(
                                                document.getString("nome").toUpperCase(),
                                                document.getString("sala"),
                                                document.getDate("datacadastro")));


                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });


    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma dica de como realizar consulta com esses tipo de campo no cloud firestore?